# mapserver layer classes display order

Tags: mapserver

My layer Point (OGR geojson) has several classes:

```
CLASS
    NAME "Station1"
    EXPRESSION ([extrude]=0)        
    STYLE
        COLOR 0 0 250
        OUTLINECOLOR 255 255 255
        SYMBOL 'circle'
        SIZE 6
    END
        LABEL
        SIZE TINY
        COLOR 0 0 0
        OUTLINECOLOR 255 255 255
        POSITION AUTO
    END
END
CLASS
    NAME "Station2"
    EXPRESSION ([extrude]=1)        
    STYLE
        COLOR 250 0 0
        OUTLINECOLOR 255 255 255
        SYMBOL 'circle'
        SIZE 10
    END
        LABEL
        SIZE TINY
        COLOR 255 0 0
        OUTLINECOLOR 255 255 255
        POSITION AUTO
    END
END    
CLASS
    NAME "Station3"
    EXPRESSION ([extrude]=2)        
    STYLE
        COLOR 128 0 128 #purple
        OUTLINECOLOR 255 255 255
        SYMBOL 'circle'
        SIZE 14
    END
        LABEL
        SIZE TINY
        COLOR 128 0 128
        OUTLINECOLOR 255 255 255
        POSITION AUTO
    END
END
```

If N points are overlaying I need to have a specific order. Station3 on top of Station2 on top of Station 1. Inverting the order nothing has changed. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use PRIORITY in LABEL:

For LABEL (http://mapserver.org/es/mapfile/label.html):

> PRIORITY [integer]|[item_name]|[attribute]
>
> The priority parameter takes an integer value between 1 (lowest) and
>   10 (highest). The default value is 1. It is also possible to bind the
>   priority to an attribute (item_name) using square brackets around the
>   [item_name]. e.g. “PRIORITY [someattribute]”
>
> Labels are stored in the label cache and rendered in order of
>   priority, with the highest priority levels rendered first. Specifying
>   an out of range PRIORITY value inside a map file will result in a
>   parsing error. An out of range value set via MapScript or coming from
>   a shape attribute will be clamped to the min/max values at rendering
>   time. There is no expected impact on performance for using label
>   priorities.
>
> [Attribute] was introduced in version 5.6.
>
> Nuevo en la versión 5.0.

another idea is to change the order of your classes, ie. put first Station3, then Station2 and so forth.

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

The only "right" way to achieve a correct alignment of the object on the map is sorting at the level of data acquisition!

Unfortunately MapServer cannot draw objects according to the order of the classes.

As a temporary solution (not very optimal), move the objects to another layer and merge them into one using:

`GROUP [name]` in Layer object

Name of a group that this layer belongs to. The group name can then be reference as a regular layer name in the template files, allowing to do things like turning on and off a group of layers at once.

If a group name is present in the LAYERS parameter of a CGI request, all the layers of the group are returned (the STATUS of the LAYERs has no effect).